# Error from PGF/TikZ .tex file from geogebra (size)

Tags: graphics, plot, size, geogebra

I am using geogebra for the first time and am having an error when I put the PGF/TikZ code into overleaf. The exact error is

> Float too large for page by 455.39223pt on input line 306.
>
> main.tex, line 304 Overfull \hbox (1140.459pt too wide) in paragraph
> at lines 304--305

Here is the code (note that the last line shown, '\end{figure}' corresponds to line 306 as in the errors above:

```
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{ffcctt}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.2}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{yqyqyq}{rgb}{0.5019607843137255,0.5019607843137255,0.5019607843137255}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\clip(-29.15527732052291,-20.111903557751653) rectangle (27.437297647521294,18.136500246696393);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=yqyqyq] (0,0) circle (6cm);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq] (0,6)-- (-4.336291901416994,-4.146875033770055);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffcctt] (0,6)-- (-2.2142787553979884,-5.576465690147581);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffcctt] (0,6)-- (2.190703198420197,-5.585769373723867);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqqqff] (0,6)-- (4.206985190994306,-4.277999018554656);
\draw (-0.10585670954964947,7.431250799319233) node[anchor=north west] {v};
\draw (-5.055017258085835,-3.9195413283017766) node[anchor=north west] {x};
\draw (-2.580436983817742,-5.533398028911399) node[anchor=north west] {y};
\draw (2.5301092347794056,-5.210626688789474) node[anchor=north west] {w};
\draw (4.628122945571919,-3.8657461049481223) node[anchor=north west] {z};
\draw [shift={(0,0)},line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq]  plot[domain=3.904665970656774:4.334406131420695,variable=\t]({1*6*cos(\t r)+0*6*sin(\t r)},{0*6*cos(\t r)+1*6*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(0,0)},line width=2pt,color=qqqqff]  plot[domain=5.08614767141132:5.4894179862449555,variable=\t]({1*6*cos(\t r)+0*6*sin(\t r)},{0*6*cos(\t r)+1*6*sin(\t r)});
\draw [color=ffqqqq](-3.3335701107689006,1.3523905603563229) node[anchor=north west] {$c_1$};
\draw [color=ffqqqq](-3.8715223443054425,-4.726469678606588) node[anchor=north west] {$c_1$};
\draw [color=ffcctt](-1.0741707299154248,-0.1000804701923371) node[anchor=north west] {$c_3$};
\draw [color=ffcctt](0.48589074734054655,-0.1000804701923371) node[anchor=north west] {$c_3$};
\draw [color=qqqqff](2.5301092347794056,1.2985953370026688) node[anchor=north west] {$c_2$};
\draw [color=qqqqff](3.4446280317915265,-4.726469678606588) node[anchor=north west] {$c_2$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=uququq] (0,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uququq] (-4.336291901416994,-4.146875033770055) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uququq] (-2.2142787553979884,-5.576465690147581) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uququq] (2.190703198420197,-5.585769373723867) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uququq] (4.206985190994306,-4.277999018554656) circle (2.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

There have been a couple of other posts about the size of images when importing from geogebra, however the answers seemed to give a corrected code without explaining how to deal with these errors in general, or how it arises, so I am not sure how to deal with my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in you case the TeX-output is rather helpful. In fact, the tikzpicture you want to render is of the size 5m wide and 3,8m high, which might not be want you want ("too large"). I suggest simply removing the line

```
\clip(-29.15527732052291,-20.111903557751653) rectangle (27.437297647521294,18.136500246696393);
```

This command adjusts the size of the tikz-picture to the rectangle specified (which adds up to the size I indicated above). Since there is nothing in your image that needs to be cut, removing it leads to a smaller size that fits into your document (in fact, it is roughly 12 x 13.5 cm). (The clip-command is most often used when you don't exactly know how large certain elements are and you just want to keep the picture to a reasonable size without computing end points of lines etc. explicitly.)

If you need to adjust it further, simply add (for example)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .5, <other options>]
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please, can you put a complete code to see your improvements?

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for the explanation of what is going on :)